# JavaScript IntersectionObserver rootMargin not working

Tags: javascript, frontend

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm currently developing a website with a Timeline to gradually show the elements and an `IntersectionObserver` to change the nav bar when it intersects a specific element (`.container`).

I'm using negative `rootMargin` and I need to set it up to `-90%` but it's only working up to `-50%`.

Does anyone know what my problem is?

**The code I'm using:**

```
function siteTimeLine() {
    let controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
    let timeline = new TimelineMax();
    
    timeline                                   
        .to('.rock', 3, {y: -300})              
        .to('.girl', 3, {y: -200}, '-=3')
        .fromTo('.bg1', {y: -50}, {y: 0, duration: 3}, '-=3')
        .to('.content', 3, {top: '0%'}, '-=3')
        .fromTo('.content-images', {opacity: 0}, {opacity: 1, duration: 2})
        .fromTo('.text', {opacity: 0}, {opacity: 1, duration: 2});
        
    let scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: '.main-section',
        duration: '200%',
        triggerHook: 0
    })
        .setTween(timeline)
        .setPin('section')
        .addTo(controller);
}


function navIntersectionObserver() {
    const navbar = document.querySelector('.nav-list');
    const initSection = document.querySelector('.content');
    const initSectionOpts = {
        //root: document.getElementsByClassName("body"),
        rootMargin: '-50%'
    };

    const initSectionObs = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, initSectionObs) {
        entries.forEach( entry => {
            if(entry.isIntersecting) {
                console.log('Intersection!');
                navbar.classList.add('nav-scrolled');

            } else {
                navbar.classList.remove('nav-scrolled');
            }
        })
    }, initSectionOpts);

    initSectionObs.observe(initSection);
}


function website() {
    navIntersectionObserver();
    siteTimeLine();
}

website();
```

Comment: Well `rootMargin` can be tricky becasue it works like common `margin` - percentage is relative to the elements bounding box. It's hard to simulate it without your HTML part. Did you try to use [`threshold`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#creating_an_intersection_observer) instead of it? A `threshold: 0.9` means that when 90% of the target is visible within the element specified by the root option, the callback is invoked. Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

Comment: @Jax-p no I actually didn't think of that, but I've just tried it and it's working as it should, thanks for the tip!